# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error for selection sort pointer char array

Tags: c, pointers, arrays, selection-sort

When i compile and run this selection sort of random char array i get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. I think it's got to do with accessing unallocated memory in my selection sort section. Can anyone help please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRING_LEN 80
#define ARRAY_LEN 10000

void *emalloc(size_t s) {
   void *result = malloc(s);
   if (NULL == result) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed!\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   return result;
}

void selection_sort(char *words[], int n) {
   char *temp;
   int i, j;

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (j = i+1; i < n; j++) {
         if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) < 0) {
            temp = words[i];
            words[i] = words[j];
            words[j] = temp;
         }
      }
   }
}

int main(void) {
   char word[STRING_LEN];
   char *wordlist[ARRAY_LEN];
   int num_words;
   int i;

   num_words = 0;
   while (num_words < ARRAY_LEN && 1 == scanf("%79s", word)) {
      wordlist[num_words] = emalloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof wordlist[0][0]);
      strcpy(wordlist[num_words], word);
      num_words++;
   }

   selection_sort(wordlist, num_words);

   for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
       printf("%s\n", wordlist[i]);
   }

   for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
      free(wordlist[i]);
   }

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Have you ran it in the debugger yet?

Comment: +1 for writing a [short, self-contained, correct compilable example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: `for(j = i + 1; i < n; j++)`  You probably want `j < n`, otherwise you're accessing outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: (Face Palm) Cheers thats a really stupid mistake and was really stumped for a few hours

Answer (score 3):

Instead of just pointing out your simple but hard-to-spot error, I'm going to walk you through how I debugged it so that you can learn how to use a debugger and solve these types of issues yourself (*teach a man to fish*, as the saying goes).

First, I compiled your code (with the warning level cranked up) and made sure I could reproduce the issue:

```
$ clang test.c -o test -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  # No warnings, great!
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar\nbaz' | ./test
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Ok, it crashed.  The issue is reproducible.  Now, recompile with debug symbols (`-g`) and setup a test vector:

```
$ clang test.c -o test -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar\nbaz' > input
```

Now run the debugger and see what happens.  I'm using LLDB on Mac OS X, but the exact same commands would work in GDB:

```
$ lldb ./test
Current executable set to './test' (x86_64).
(lldb) run < input
Process 68367 launched: './test' (x86_64)
Process 68367 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x553a95, 0x00007fff918e0db5 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strcmp + 181, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff918e0db5 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strcmp + 181
libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strcmp + 181:
-> 0x7fff918e0db5:  movdqu (%rsi,%rcx), %xmm1
   0x7fff918e0dba:  pcmpeqb %xmm1, %xmm0
   0x7fff918e0dbe:  pcmpeqb %xmm2, %xmm1
   0x7fff918e0dc2:  pandn  %xmm0, %xmm1
```

We crashed inside the `strcmp()` function on a null pointer (the `address=0x0` part).  Now how did we get there and why did that happen?  Here's the stack trace:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x553a95, 0x00007fff918e0db5 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strcmp + 181, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff918e0db5 libsystem_platform.dylib`_platform_strcmp + 181
    frame #1: 0x0000000100000c96 test`selection_sort(words=0x00007fff5fbec1a0, n=3) + 86 at test.c:23
    frame #2: 0x0000000100000e03 test`main + 243 at test.c:45
```

Let's move up to where we called `strcmp()`:

```
(lldb) up 1
frame #1: 0x0000000100000c96 test`selection_sort(words=0x00007fff5fbec1a0, n=3) + 86 at test.c:23
   20   
   21      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   22         for (j = i+1; i < n; j++) {
-> 23            if (strcmp(words[i], words[j]) < 0) {
   24               temp = words[i];
   25               words[i] = words[j];
   26               words[j] = temp;
```

Now let's see what we were calling `strcmp()` with (`p` is shorthand for `print`):

```
(lldb) p words[i]
(char *) $0 = 0x0000000100103920 "foo"
(lldb) p words[j]
(char *) $1 = 0x0000000000000000
```

Welp, there's our null pointer.  How did that happen?  What are `i` and `j`?

```
(lldb) p i
(int) $2 = 0
(lldb) p j
(int) $3 = 3
```

Oh no!  `j` is 3, but it shouldn't ever be 3 or more, since `n` is 3 (since we had 3 lines in the input file).  Shouldn't our loop prevent `j` from exceeding `n`...?  Take a closer look:

```
22            for (j = i+1; i < n; j++) {
```

Oops—there's the bug.  The loop test is `i < n` when it should really be `j < n`.  `j` grows without bound until it crashes or something else bad happens (like an attacker taking over your system if the input data were specially crafted to exploit this).

Here are some links to help learn how to use command line debuggers such as LLDB and GDB:

- [LLDB Tutorial](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html)
- [GDB Tutorial](http://www.dirac.org/linux/gdb/)
- [GDB Cheat Sheet](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html)